# The setting to turn Bluetooth on or off has disappeared

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

I can't turn on my Bluetooth. In the settings menu there is no option available to turn it off or on. It has been like this for a few weeks, but I don't know why it happened.

This can be seen in the screenshot:

[image: settings menu screenshot]

I've already tried to update the Bluetooth driver, but I can't find any Bluetooth drivers:

[image: device manager screenshot]

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I would like to have my Bluetooth back!

Comment: We'll need at least the computer model

Comment: Right click on Unknown devices, select Properties and check its VID/PID

Comment: Not sure why this isn't an answer to "I would like to have my Bluetooth back", as this will get it back, but I'll add it as a comment instead:

If you shut the computer down completely (not restart, but "Shut Down"), when you start, it comes back (for me, anyhow). Eventually, it will fail again, but then you just repeat the shut down/start cycle.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem with a Gigabyte laptop P55Wv7. All drivers are up to date as I have used the Intel driver and support assistant to update to last ones. It didn´t help.
I noticed that once w10 starts the switch is visible during around 10 secs. Then it dissapears. What I tried is to start switching on and of and on again during 15 secs and then it remains visible. I know weird work around but it works and now I can use my Bose QC35 bluetooth earphones

Answer (score 0):

1. Bring up the start menu. Search for "Device Manager".
2. Go to "View" and click "Show hidden devices"
3. In Device Manager, expand Bluetooth.
4. Right click on Bluetooth Generic Adapter and update the driver.

Restart the PC to check the results.

Comment: The answer isn't right.  What happened in my case was the bluetooth icon was missing from the ^ selection in the toolbar, that is you click on the '^' icon and its not even in the flyout panel

I had to cold reboot to get it back.

There was NO 'Bluetooth Generic Adapter' in Bluetooth in Device Manager to download a driver or update one.

There IS a bug in Windows 10 where my mouse mysteriously freezes ONLY on my home network.  I go to the Microsoft store and it works.  They can never find what is up.